# No column name was specified for column1 of 'TableA'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Anyone please point me why I am getting this error?

```
SELECT imax, iResult
FROM(
    SELECT 
        top 20000 CAST(Pro_PCT AS INT), 
        CAST(REPLACE(Max_Off,'%','') AS INT) AS 'iMax',
        iif(CAST(Pro_PCT AS INT)> CAST(
    REPLACE(Max_Off,'%','') AS INT),'Yes','No') AS 'iResult'
FROM 
    dbo.FO_Entry) AS TableA
WHERE iResult = 'yes'
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and `AS 'iMax'` is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a columnname CAST(Pro_PCT AS INT) that's why it gives that error:

```
SELECT imax, iResult
FROM(
    SELECT 
        top 20000 CAST(Pro_PCT AS INT) as pro_pct, 
        CAST(REPLACE(Max_Off,'%','') AS INT) AS 'iMax',
        iif(CAST(Pro_PCT AS INT)> CAST(
    REPLACE(Max_Off,'%','') AS INT),'Yes','No') AS 'iResult'
FROM 
    dbo.FO_Entry) AS TableA
WHERE iResult = 'yes'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake.  It works now.  SO says, I have to wait 10 minutes to mark yours as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `case` expression instead :

```
SELECT imax, iResult
FROM( SELECT TOP (20000) CAST(Pro_PCT AS INT) AS Pro_PCT,  CAST(REPLACE(Max_Off,'%','') AS INT) AS iMax,
             (CASE WHEN CAST(Pro_PCT AS INT) > CAST(REPLACE(Max_Off,'%','') AS INT) 
                   THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' 
              END) AS iResult
      FROM dbo.FO_Entry
    ) AS TableA
WHERE iResult = 'yes';
```

Comment: @Sixthsense . . . `case` is ISO/ANSI standard syntax.  `IIF()` was introduced to SQL Server for backwards compatibility to *MS Access* (as if such compatibility were a good thing).  `CASE` is definitely preferable for the vast majority of database users.